# Speed up index "revert"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array `a` of shape `(n, 3)` filled with integers from `0` to `m`. Both `m` and `n` can be fairly large. It is known that every integer from `0` to `m` appears sometimes only once, but mostly exactly twice somewhere in `a`. There are no doubled indices in a row.

I would now like to construct the "reverse" index, i.e., two arrays `b_row` and `b_col` of shape `(m, 2)` that for each row contains the (one or two) row/column indices into `a` where `row_idx` appears in `a`.

This works:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 1, 3],
    [2, 3, 4],
    [4, 5, 6],
    # ...
    ])

print(a)

b_row = -numpy.ones((7, 2), dtype=int)
b_col = -numpy.ones((7, 2), dtype=int)
count = numpy.zeros(7, dtype=int)
for k, row in enumerate(a):
    i = count[row]
    b_row[row, i] = k
    b_col[row, i] = [0, 1, 2]
    count[row] += 1

print(b_row)
print(b_col)
```

```
[[0 1 2]
 [0 1 3]
 [2 3 4]
 [4 5 6]]

[[ 0  1]
 [ 0  1]
 [ 0  2]
 [ 1  2]
 [ 2  3]
 [ 3 -1]
 [ 3 -1]]

[[ 0  0]
 [ 1  1]
 [ 2  0]
 [ 2  1]
 [ 2  0]
 [ 1 -1]
 [ 2 -1]]
```

but is slow because of the explicit loop over `a`.

Any hints on how to speed this up?

Comment: I noticed there is a bug in your code, `count[row] += 1` should be `np.add.at(count, row, 1)`, otherwise it may fail when one element appears more than once in the same row. Also, since you edited your question after I posted my answer I assume you have seen it; it would be helpful to know whether you found it useful or not, and why in that case.

Comment: Actually, there's still another error for multiple elements in the same row, `i` is not correct in that case. One way of fixing it is `i = count[row] + np.sum(np.triu(row == row[:, np.newaxis]), axis=0) - 1`

Comment: Very well spotted! This is indeed an assumption I silently made, and it's true in my application. I added the statement to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that only uses one `argsort` and a bunch of light index manipulations:

```
def grp_start_len(a):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/50394587/353337
    m = numpy.concatenate([[True], a[:-1] != a[1:], [True]])
    idx = numpy.flatnonzero(m)
    return idx[:-1], numpy.diff(idx)


a_flat = a.flatten()

idx_sort = numpy.argsort(a_flat)

idx_start, count = grp_start_len(a_flat[idx_sort])

res1 = idx_sort[idx_start[count==1]][:, numpy.newaxis]
res1 // 3
res1 % 3

idx = idx_start[count==2]
res2 = numpy.column_stack([idx_sort[idx], idx_sort[idx + 1]])
res2 // 3
res2 % 3
```

The basic idea is that, after `a` is flattened and sorted, all the information can be extracted from the starting indices and the lenghts of the integer blocks in `a_flat_sorted`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
import numpy as np

m = 7
a = np.array([
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 1, 3],
    [2, 3, 4],
    [4, 5, 6],
    # ...
    ])

print('a:')
print(a)

a_flat = a.flatten()  # Or a.ravel() if can modify original array
v1, idx1 = np.unique(a_flat, return_index=True)
a_flat[idx1] = -1
v2, idx2 = np.unique(a_flat, return_index=True)
v2, idx2 = v2[1:], idx2[1:]
rows1, cols1 = np.unravel_index(idx1, a.shape)
rows2, cols2 = np.unravel_index(idx2, a.shape)
b_row = -np.ones((m, 2), dtype=int)
b_col = -np.ones((m, 2), dtype=int)
b_row[v1, 0] = rows1
b_col[v1, 0] = cols1
b_row[v2, 1] = rows2
b_col[v2, 1] = cols2

print('b_row:')
print(b_row)
print('b_col:')
print(b_col)
```

Output:

```
a:
[[0 1 2]
 [0 1 3]
 [2 3 4]
 [4 5 6]]
b_row:
[[ 0  1]
 [ 0  1]
 [ 0  2]
 [ 1  2]
 [ 2  3]
 [ 3 -1]
 [ 3 -1]]
b_col:
[[ 0  0]
 [ 1  1]
 [ 2  0]
 [ 2  1]
 [ 2  0]
 [ 1 -1]
 [ 2 -1]]
```

*EDIT:*

A small benchmark in IPython for comparison. As indicated by [@eozd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4098186/eozd) the algorithmic complexity is in principle higher due to `np.unique` running in O(n), but the vectorized solution seems to be still much faster for practical sizes:

```
import numpy as np

def method_orig(a, m):
    b_row = -np.ones((m, 2), dtype=int)
    b_col = -np.ones((m, 2), dtype=int)
    count = np.zeros(m, dtype=int)
    for k, row in enumerate(a):
        i = count[row]
        b_row[row, i] = k
        b_col[row, i] = [0, 1, 2]
        count[row] += 1
    return b_row, b_col

def method_jdehesa(a, m):
    a_flat = a.flatten()  # Or a.ravel() if can modify original array
    v1, idx1 = np.unique(a_flat, return_index=True)
    a_flat[idx1] = -1
    v2, idx2 = np.unique(a_flat, return_index=True)
    v2, idx2 = v2[1:], idx2[1:]
    rows1, cols1 = np.unravel_index(idx1, a.shape)
    rows2, cols2 = np.unravel_index(idx2, a.shape)
    b_row = -np.ones((m, 2), dtype=int)
    b_col = -np.ones((m, 2), dtype=int)
    b_row[v1, 0] = rows1
    b_col[v1, 0] = cols1
    b_row[v2, 1] = rows2
    b_col[v2, 1] = cols2
    return b_row, b_col

n = 100000
c = 3
m = 200000

# Generate random input
# This does not respect "no doubled indices in row" but is good enough for testing
np.random.seed(100)
a = np.random.permutation(np.concatenate([np.arange(m), np.arange(m)]))[:(n * c)].reshape((n, c))

%timeit method_orig(a, m)
# 3.22 s ± 1.3 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit method_jdehesa(a, m)
# 108 ms ± 764 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Although it uses vectorized operations, doesn't this have higher time complexity than a single loop (`O(nlogn)` vs `O(n)`)? I assume `np.unique` runs in `O(nlogn)` time; correct me if it doesn't.

Comment: @eozd Yes, you're right about that, thanks for pointing it out. It's a shame, because I think `np.unique` should be possible to run in `O(n)` if it offered the option not to require ordered output. Pandas `pd.unique` is faster but it cannot return indices so cannot be used here. In any case I added a small benchmark for comparison and the vectorized solution seems to be still much faster (I guess at some huge size maybe not but probably that wouldn't fit in your memory anyway...).